# How to stop URL redirect when trailing slash is omitted?

Tags: .htaccess

I wrote htaccess rewrite rule to get the content from another folder. For example: if the URL is `http://test.com/folder2/folder3/` then the index file is loaded from the `folder1/folder2/folder3` directory. All is working well in this case but if I omit the trailing slash in the URL i.e. if the URL is `http://test.com/folder2/folder3` then the URL is redirected to `http://test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/`. How do I load the content from `folder1/folder2/folder3` without changing the URL?

The rewrite rule is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(folder2/.*)$ folder1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but make the `/` optional. like `RewriteRule ^(folder2/.*)/?$ folder1/$1 [L]`

Comment: Already tried that. Adding it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem by forcing trailing slash to every URLs. So, the `.htaccess` file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(folder2/.*)$ folder1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is due to `mod_dir` module running after `mod_dir` and adding a trailing slah on rewritten URI. You can change your htaccess to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder1/$1 -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^(folder2/.*)$ folder1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry I meant **`mod_dir` module running after `mod_rewrite` module**

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but using the above code, even the URL which was working previously stopped working.

Comment: None of the URLs `http://test.com/folder2/folder3` or `http://test.com/folder2/folder3/` were working.  I got `404` error in both the cases, but now `http://test.com/folder2/folder3/` is working as intended but `http://test.com/folder2/folder3` gives a `403` error.

Comment: I'm not getting a `403 error` anymore but still `http://test.com/folder2/folder3` redirects to `http://test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/`.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me, make sure to test in a new browser to clear browser cache and then test.

Comment: I did that and still got the same results as before.

Comment: As I said above exact same code worked for me without doing any redirect in browser. Make sure you copy paste again properly and don't have any other rule while testing this.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'm still getting the same results. I tried it in a completely different browser and also there were no other rules.

Comment: Show your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: The .htaccess is exactly the same as the one you posted, except that the folder names have been changed to real folder names in the project. Do I also need to enable some other apache modules for this to work?

Comment: No not really. Also try adding `DirectorySlash off` on top of your .htaccess